# why I can not library(mice) in r

Tags: r-mice

after install.packages(mice) successfully, I couldn't library(mice). and the Error as follow:

> library(mice)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’:
> object ‘local_seed’ is not exported by 'namespace:withr'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The package `mice` relies - among others - on the package `withr`. It seems that this one is not installed properly. Do `install.packages("withr")` and see if it installs properly. Also check, if you can get the function `withr::local_seed`. If so, try `library(mice)` again.